# Running into a SubprocessError for Ionic v4 production build

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, ionic4

I'm currently running into issues with Ionic v4 production builds.
After running an `ionic build --prod` on my Ubuntu v.18 machine I'll
receive this strange error:

```
Error at new SubprocessError
(/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.2.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:40:23)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
(/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.2.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:124:27)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1011:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:5)
```

Can anyone interpret this error? I just checked out my repo which build fine on my OSX machine under the same version of node (v.12.2) and made an npm install.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.900.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.1.2",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.21.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.21.3",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.21.3",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.10",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "date-fns": "^2.9.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score -1):

just remove :  node-modules & package-lock.json
then npm install